# How to do a maximum point projection from a multidimensional Mask image in python

Tags: python

I have created a mask for each slice in my multidimensional image I am then trying to stack them so that I have a complete one dimensional image that can then be used as a mask defining the outline.

```
def MaxPP(img):
    numSlice = img.shape[0]
    max = np.empty(shape=(numSlice,512,512),dtype=bool)
    for i in range(0,numSlice):
        test = img[i,:,:]
        max += test
    return max
```

This returns an image that seems to work in my console but not work on in my code

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify the code as follows:

```
def MaxPP(img):
    return np.sum(img, axis=0)
```